# Codeigniter:Ajax infinite scroll with filter

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, codeigniter-3

I want to create pagination page into infinite scroll with filters. I'm using codeigniter. Pagination is working fine. When passing checkbox values(for filter) to controller it showing null.when clicking check box its not alert data. I had struggle for days. I will be so grateful if you can help me. Thank you.

Ajax

```js
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var total_record = 0;
        var total_groups = <?php echo $total_data; ?>;  
    //brand is the checkbox value
        var brand=check_box_values('brand');
        $('#results').load("<?php echo base_url() ?>content/load_more",
         {'group_no':total_record,'brand':brand}, function() {total_record++;});
        $(window).scroll(function() {       
            if($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height() >= $('#fooerdivid').offset().top)  
            {           
                if(total_record <= total_groups)
                {
                  loading = true; 
                  $('.loader_image').show(); 
                  $.post('<?php echo site_url() ?>content/load_more',{'group_no': total_record,'brand':brand},
                    function(data){ 
                        if (data != "") {                               
                            $("#results").append(data);                 
                            $('.loader_image').hide();                  
                            total_record++;
                        }
                    });     
                }
            }
        });
    //For passing checkbox values
         function check_box_values(check_box_class){
                var values = new Array();
                    $("."+check_box_class+":checked").each(function() {
                       values.push($(this).val());
                    });
                return values;
            }
        });
        </script>
```

Controller

```html
public function load_more()
    {
        $group_no = $this->input->post('group_no');
        $brand = $this->input->post('brand');
        $content_per_page = 5;
        $start = ceil($group_no * $content_per_page);
        $all_content = $this->content_model->get_all_content($start,$content_per_page,$brand);
        if(isset($all_content) && is_array($all_content) && count($all_content)) : 
            foreach ($all_content as $key => $content) :
                 echo '<li>'.$content->title.'</li>';
                 echo '<p>'.$content->description.'</p>';                 
            endforeach;                                
        endif; 
    }
```

Model

```html
public function get_all_content($start,$content_per_page,$brand)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM  content_information LIMIT $start,$content_per_page";      
        if(isset($brand))// your condition here  
{
$this->db->where_in('brand', $brand);
}
        $result = $this->db->query($sql)->result();
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Where is your PHP code?

Comment: posted php code @Smit Ravel

Comment: When you post brand, are you sure you have a data in your db between limit and offset?

Comment: that not the problem i was unable pass the value when check box is clicked please have a look at view code.@Smit Raval

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code. On document.ready function call the function to load first data. On click event of checkboxes you need to call the function again to get the next data.Also on window.scroll you have to load the data.

```
           $(document).ready(function() {
    load_content();
    function load_content(){
            var total_record = 0;
            var total_groups = <?php echo $total_data; ?>;  
        //brand is the checkbox value
            var brand=check_box_values('brand');
            $('#results').load("<?php echo base_url() ?>content/load_more",
             {'group_no':total_record,'brand':brand}, function() {total_record++;});        
     }
        //For passing checkbox values
             function check_box_values(check_box_class){
                        var values = new Array();
                            $("."+check_box_class).each(function() {
                              if($(this).is(':checked')){
                               values.push($(this).val());
                                }
                            });
                        return values;
                    }
        $(".brand").click(function(){
          load_content();
       });

$(window).scroll(function() {       
                if($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height() >= $('#fooerdivid').offset().top)  
                {           
                   var total_record = 0;
            var total_groups = <?php echo $total_data; ?>;  
        //brand is the checkbox value
            var brand=check_box_values('brand');

                    if(total_record <= total_groups)
                    {
                      loading = true; 
                      $('.loader_image').show(); 
                      $.post('<?php echo site_url() ?>content/load_more',{'group_no': total_record,'brand':brand},
                        function(data){ 
                            if (data != "") {                               
                                $("#results").append(data);                 
                                $('.loader_image').hide();                  
                                total_record++;
                            }
                        });     
                    }
                }
            });
    });
```

Please ignore syntax errors as I have not tested the code but you will get an idea from this.

Comment: Welcome brother @DingoGhatr